# Unable to modify an object returned by an R function

Tags: r

I wrote a function in R to return the name of the first column of a data frame:

```
my_func <- function(table, firstColumnOnly = TRUE){
  if(firstColumnOnly)
    return(colnames(table)[1])
  else
    return(colnames(table))
}
```

If I call the function like this:

```
my_func(fertility)<-"foo"
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in my_func(fertility, FALSE)[1] <- "foo" : 
  could not find function "my_func<-"
```

Why am I getting this error?  I can do this without an error:

```
colnames(fertility)[1]<-"Country"
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You currently seem to be assigning a string to function output. That's not the way to go.

Comment: R tells you that there is no function called "my_func<-", you only defined a function called "my_func", which you did not call correctly. What do you think is `foo` here? (I'm trying to make sense of what you are trying to do)

Comment: I guess if you just turn it around to `foo <- my_func( fertility )` you are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are expecting that this:

```
my_func(fertility)<-"foo"
```

will be understood by R as:

```
colnames(table)[1] <- "foo" # if firstColumnOnly
```

or

```
colnames(table) <- "foo"    # if !firstColumnOnly
```

It will not. One reason for this is that `colnames()` and `colnames()<-` are two *distinct* functions. The first one returns the column names, the second one assigns new names. Your function can only return the names, not assign them.

One workaround would be to write your function using `colnames()<-`:

```
my_func <- function(table, rep, firstColumnOnly = TRUE){
  if(firstColumnOnly) colnames(table)[1] <- rep
  else colnames(table) <- rep
  return(table)
}
```

Test

```
head(my_func(iris,"foo"))
      foo Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1 5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2 4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3 4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4 4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5 5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6 5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm totally new to R programming, didn't know that there was a colnames<- function, and didn't know about this programming paradigm in R.